# Find methods of an IronPython class from C#

Tags: ironpython

Is there a way to reflect an IronPython class to find its methods from C#? I can do this for IronRuby by RubyClass and RubyMethodInfo. Are there similar classes for IronPython? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .NET 4 or higher, this is easy  if you just let python do it for you:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var script = @"
            class TestObject:
                def Member1(self):
                     pass
        ";
        var setup = new ScriptRuntimeSetup();
        setup.LanguageSetups.Add(Python.CreateLanguageSetup(null));

        var runtime = new ScriptRuntime(setup);
        var engine = runtime.GetEngineByTypeName(typeof(PythonContext).AssemblyQualifiedName);

        var scope = engine.CreateScope();
        engine.Execute(script, scope);

        foreach (var member in GetMembers(engine, ((dynamic)scope).TestObject))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(member);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Make sure to adjust the sample script comment block to fix the indentation.

Then just create a method that can do the inspection for you for any object (Python or C#)

```
 static dynamic GetMembers(ScriptEngine engine, dynamic obj)
 {
        var scope = engine.CreateScope();
        scope.SetVariable("objectToInspect", obj);
        return engine.Execute("def i(obj): l = dir(obj); l.sort(); return l;\ni(objectToInspect)", scope);
 }
```

This prints:

```
Member1
__doc__
__module__
```

Comment: foreach (var member in GetMembers(engine, ((dynamic)scope).TestObject))
  May I know what is TestObject here?